# Symfony: How to force a password reset for a user after login/during an active session

Tags: php, symfony

I have a `User` entity with a `resetPassword` property on it. It's boolean, if `true` the user should be redirected to a `resetPassword` form.

At the moment I have this logic in my DefaultController. When someone hits the index route the controller action checks for the flag and renders a `resetPasswordType` form when needed. It's OK but far from ideal: without cut/pasting code it won't apply to all routes.

What is the best practice to properly implement this?

I've had a few ideas:

- An event listener like the one [described here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html) might do the trick. I have tried it, and I managed to get the user token and got the check to work but I'm not sure what the best way to render the formType is from there. Maybe I could just redirect to a route from the event listener, but again I'm not 100% sure on how to do this.
- A custom [userChecker](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/user_checkers.html). This would only work after login but that's OK in this case. Again, I have tried it, it worked, but I'm not sure on how to render the form from there.
- Some sort of custom [redirect after success](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/form_login.html) but I'm not sure on where to actually do the check on the `resetPassword` flag in this case.

Any opinions/advice welcome.

Comment: Your event listener is you best bet.  Just have it redirect to your reset password route.

Answer (score 0):

Create MY_Controller.php in application/core:

```
  class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();



        //do your works...
}
}
```

Then , extends all your controllers :

```
class your_controller extends MY_Controller {}
```

Your code will run befor any controller (extented from MY_Controller ) run.

Comment: No.  Just no.  Using inheritance for this sort of thing is almost always the wrong approach.  The Symfony framework provides a number of more appropriate alternatives.

Comment: why did i think we are talking about CodeIgniter? sorry

Comment: Partly my fault, I have edited the title to make it clearer.